# How to handle iOS popup in webdriverIO and mocha?

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I'm working on the Android and iOS app automation using the WebdriverIO. I'm unable to inspect the pop up in the browser stack inspect view.

Could you please assist on this?

Comment: Try using Appium Inspector tool with BrowserStack App Automate, for documentation, here: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with browser.dismissAlert() and it worked.

In the page file, I defined this function like this:

**page.js**

```
 async popupHandle() {
     browser.dismissAlert()
 }
```

In the test file, I use it like this:

**test.js**

```
await page.popupHandle()
```

Answer (score 3):

I also couldn't inspect native alerts in the Browserstack but I opened the app with the Appium Inspector:

[appium inspector in the browserstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Vll.png)

and then I could inspect easily

[appium inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T5uq.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34671321)